# JQuery corner plugin with images - firefox issue

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, rounded-corners

The plugin JQuery corner is designed to round the corners using jquery of containers and objects. Contrary to every example on the demo page http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/ but written in the docs I have rounded the corners of a container with an image inside it. The image has consequently also rounded.

This is working in ::

Safari, Mobile Safari, Google Chrome

I cannot get it to work in Firefox or IE. I have set up a fiddle if anyone can work it out.
http://jsfiddle.net/ywSar/1/

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: In this day and age, you're probably better off rounding your corners with CSS.  Those DOM-mangling plugins have always seemed like a real pain to deal with, in my experience.

Comment: I tried this to begin with, but how can you round the corners of an image.

Comment: Firefox 4 renders the corners of an image in a container with rounded corners correctly, but 3.6 and earlier don't. The overflow:hidden is just ignored for the corner area.

Comment: Hi ho. Another plugin fixed it with some significant tweeking

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else whom encounters this problem.

Use the plugin `jquery.curvycorners` instead.

- This can handle backgrounds-images behind it rather than just being one colour.

Then change the images to background inside a DIV object instead. This will fix the problem in all browsers defaulting to CSS3 properties in modern browsers and applying the script in older ones.

Marvellous